# WFS with authentication to PostGis (or to shape)

Tags: postgis, shapefile, wfs

Is there a way to import data from a WFS layer to a Postgis table (or to a shape)? 
there are blogs explaining how to do it in 3 steps (http://anitagraser.com/2012/09/26/wfs-to-postgis-in-3-steps/) or just in 1 (http://anitagraser.com/2012/09/29/wfs-to-postgis-in-one-step/) but in none of them is explained how to pass the USERNAME and the PASSWORD required by the WFS service.

If i could export the WFS layer to the shape, then i could convert the shape easily in a postgis table.
But, again, the problem is in the HTTP authentication.

Any suggestion?

---

I think that the problem is that "GDAL/OGR must be built with Curl support in order to the WFS driver to be compiled" as is written here: http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html.

And i suppose i didn't have GDAL built with Curl support then i receive the FAILURE message (Unable to open datasource).

Now the problem is:
Is this hypotesis true?
and.. 
how to build GDAL with Curl on CentOS?

Comment: It might depend on how the www server implements user authentication (ie, basic vs digest vs ldap, or other means). But you could try to use the UserPwd option for WFS' in ogr2ogr as a first attempt. See http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html

Comment: The server has a Basic authentication. I'm able to connect the service with Geoserver or Qgis.
I've tryed also with a XML files (named OGR_WFS_FnsNSWFS.xml):

<OGRWFSDataSource>
<URL>http://remoteserver:8081/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&amp;TYPENAME=outWork:remotelayer&amp;SRSNAME=EPSG:4326</URL>
<Version>1.0.0</Version>
<Timeout>120</Timeout>
<UserPwd>myuser:mypassword</UserPwd>
</OGRWFSDataSource>

then running the following command:
ogrinfo -ro OGR_WFS_FnsNSWFS.xml

but the answer was:
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `OGR_WFS_FnsNSWFS.xml' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
..